# No such table error in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I made a table in SQLite browser and import the data in assets folder in adnroid,now i am getting an error no such table, in my logcat,this is my code...

---

```
public class CardDatabase {

    private static final String TB_CARD_ID="CARD_ID";
    private static final String TB_CARD_QUESTION="CARD_QUESTION";
    private static final String TB_CARD_ANSWER="CARD_ANSWER";

    public static final String TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE TB_CARDS (" + " CARD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                    " CARD_QUESTION VARCHAR ," +
            " CARD_ANSWER VARCHAR);"

            ;

    private final Context context;
    public static MydataBasehelper DBHelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public CardDatabase(Context ctx)
    {Log.e("problem","here2");
            Log.e("info","database called");
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new MydataBasehelper(context);

            try 
            {
                DBHelper.createDataBase();
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe)
           {
                 throw new Error("Unable to create database");
     }

        try {

            DBHelper.openDataBase();

            }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {

            throw sqle;
        }



    }
    public CardDatabase open() throws SQLException {db =
    DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();return this;}

    public void close() {DBHelper.close();}



    public static  void insert(

                    String CARD_ID,
                    String CARD_QUESTION,
                    String CARD_ANSWER


    ){
                            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(TB_CARD_ID,CARD_ID);
            initialValues.put(TB_CARD_QUESTION,CARD_QUESTION);
            initialValues.put(TB_CARD_ANSWER,CARD_ANSWER);





            try{
            Log.e("HERE IT IS", CARD_ID);


            }catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("here","null");
                }

            db.insert("TB_CARDS", null, initialValues);

    }
    public static void truncate(){
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM TB_CARDS");
    }
    public static void deletetable(){db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TB_CARDS");}
    public static void createtable(){db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);}

    public Cursor getrecord( String CARD_ID){
            Log.e("we are","here");
            Cursor mCursor= db.query("TB_CARDS", new String[] {
                            TB_CARD_ID,
                            TB_CARD_QUESTION,
                            TB_CARD_ANSWER,


            },TB_CARD_ID  + "=" +"'"+ CARD_ID+ "'"
            ,null,null,null,null,null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                    mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
    }
    Cursor cur;
    public Cursor selectAll(){

        try{
        String query="SELECT * FROM TB_CARDS";
        System.out.println(query);
        cur= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("problem");
        }
        return cur;

    }
```

---

AND this is mydatabasehelper..

```
    public class MydataBasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    private static final String TAG = "info";

      private static final String DB_NAME = "flipdata1";
      private static final String DB_PATH="data/data/cue.flip/databases/";
      private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1332;

      private  Context mycontext;

    public MydataBasehelper(Context context) 

    {


        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("info","dataHelper");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {



    //  Log.e("aashish","table create was called");

        //db.execSQL(CardDatabase.TABLE_CREATE);

        //db.execSQL(Question_database.TABLE_CREATE);
        //db.execSQL(Answers_Database.TABLE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
            int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TB_CARDS");




        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Question_database.DATABASE_TABLE);
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Answers_Database.DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
     public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        System.out.println("Create database");
            if(dbExist){

                System.out.println("database exists");

                //do nothing - database already exist.
            }else{

                System.out.println("database not exists");

                //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
                      //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

           }
           @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();

                super.close();

        }
           private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){

                //database does't exist yet.

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
           }

           /**
            * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
            * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
            * This is done by transfering bytestream.
            * */
           private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

               System.out.println("Copy STARTSSS");
            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();

            myInput.close();

            System.out.println("CopYY DONE");
           }
           public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
               System.out.println("OPEN DATABASE");
               String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

           }



}
```

---

Please Help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comment from second line of ON CREATE function in databasehelper class, update database version to 1333 and run.

the on-create function is supposed to be invoked if every time even if the database is created for the first time or many times !

Comment: thanks @khurram its work but i got new error....
CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: I cannot tell the exact location of error unless I take a look at you log but it occurs probably when you are retrieving data from the database. Look at those functions where you are doing it  also  this error occurs when you play with the cursor's object to extract data